# Is there a Keras function to count the total number of units?

Tags: keras

Keras has a **count_param()** Python function to count the total number of **trainable parameters** of an Artificial Neural Network (ANN) model.

```
model.count_params()
```

In the same vein, is there a Keras function to count the total number of **units** of an ANN model?

Comment: Do you want something generalizable to any network or just fully-connected networks?

Comment: Actually, I would like a solution that works for the lstm_seq2seq example (c.f. https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/ ). There is no dropout but there are LSTM units, so I'm not sure whether it is a fully-connected network  or not

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like there's an easy way out of this. For example the Input layer would return a list of tuples where (most of?) other layers return just a tuple. But the following function should work in most cases.

As it is apparent, this function takes in a model and returns two outputs.

- Total number of output units
- Output units in each layer as a list

Let me know if it doesn't work for any particular case (because I haven't tested this exhaustively)

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain
import operator 
def count_units(model):
  tot_out = 0
  out_list = []
  for lyr in model.layers:
    if lyr.trainable:
      # This is to tackle any layers that have the output shape as a list of tuples (e.g Input layer)
      if isinstance(lyr.output_shape, list):
        curr_out = reduce(operator.mul, chain(*[s[1:] for s in lyr.output_shape]), 1)
      # This is to tackle other layers like Dense and Conv2D
      elif isinstance(lyr.output_shape, tuple):
        curr_out = reduce(operator.mul, lyr.output_shape[1:], 1)
      else:
        raise TypeError
      tot_out += curr_out
      out_list.append(curr_out)
  return tot_out, out_list

print(count_units(model))
```

Comment: It works well on "basic" ANNs, but not on ANN containing LSTM.

Comment: @XavierM, I actually tested this on an LSTM and it worked. But it depends on what sort of an output you need. For example, let's say you use `LSTM(return_sequences=True)`, this will output units as `timesteps*n_units`. But if you only want `n_units` you probably need to do if else based on layer type

Comment: I defined output size as everything multiplied except batch size as that generalizes to Dense, Conv2D, LSTM all at once (if you assume the above way of computing the units)